# Xampp website suddenly not working

Tags: xampp

I am currently doing my A level coursework and as i went to finish my testing with screenshots, i opened up xampp and it displayed these messages when trying to login into my shop and also while trying to access the PHPMyAdmin.
I have no idea why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.[PhpMyAdmin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY6QW.png)
[Xampp Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7uTM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first screenshot indicate that you entered some wrong credentials (username or password or both) so you should check them out.
If you haven't change them then the default password and username are :
Username: root
Password: [null]

As for the second screenshot it's kind of the same problem 
the user millo it's not recognized so check your code/config